# Proving a function on the discrete metric is continuous

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $X$ be a set with the discrete metric and $f: X \to Y$ a map of sets underlying metric spaces. Then $f$ is automatically continuous.

The lecture notes I'm working through don't present the alternative notion of "continuous if and only if the inverse image of open sets is open" until long after this, so I think I'm expected to solve this using using distances. The proof involving this alternative definition seems straightforward enough to me once I know that every subset $S \subset X$ is open in the discrete metric, because then the inverse image of any open subset of $Y$ is by definition a subset of $X$ and hence open.

Proving it with distances, I'd need to show that given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $x' \in X$ satisfying $d_X(x,x') < \delta$, we have $d_Y (f(x), f(x') < \epsilon$. If I pick $\delta = 1$, then $d_X (x,x') < 1$, so $d_X (x,x') = 0$, so $x = x'$. Then $f(x) = f(x')$, so $d_Y (f(x), f(x')) = 0 < \epsilon$.

Is this the standard proof involving distances?

Comment: This seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $X$  be a set with the discrete metric and $  f:X \to Y$  a map of
> sets underlying metric spaces. Then $  f $  is automatically
> continuous.

Now, let's play with sequences. As long as you are in Hausdorff space, sequence is an important tool to play with limits.

In a discrete space $(X, d_{discrete}) $ , we can classify all convergent sequences. A sequence $(x_n) $ is convergent in $(X, d_{discrete}) $  iff it is eventually constant i.e $$\exists N\in \Bbb{N} , x_n=x_0 , \forall n>N$$

$  f:X \to Y$ is continuous at $x_0 \in X$ if for every sequence $(x_n) \subseteq X$ with $x_n \to x_0 $ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x_0) $ in $(Y, d')$.

As, $x_n\to x_0, \exists N\in \Bbb{N} , x_n=x_0 , \forall n>N$

Then, $f(x_n) =f(x_0), \forall n>N$

Implies, $f(x_n) \to f(x_0) $ in $(Y, d') $

Hence, $  f:X \to Y$ is continuous at  $x_0$.

Since, $x_0 \in X$ is arbitrary, $f$ is globally continuous on $(X, d_{discrete}) $